# Variable changes for unknown reason

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#it's python 3.2.3
class point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __eq__(self, point):
        return self.x == point.x and self.y == point.y

    def __str__(self):
        return 'point(%s, %s)' % (self.x, self.y)

def someFunc(point):
    if point.x > 14: point.x = 14
    elif point.x < 0: point.x = 0

    if point.y > 14: point.y = 14
    elif point.y < 0: point.y = 0

    return point

somePoint = point(-1, -1)
print('ONE: %s' % somePoint)
if somePoint == someFunc(somePoint):
    print('TWO: %s' % somePoint)
```

I see that there is no **somePoint** variable assignment after first **print()**
but variable **somePoint** magically changes after **if** statement

Output of this program should be

```
ONE: point(-1, -1)
```

But it is

```
ONE: point(-1, -1)
TWO: point(0, 0)
```

Could anybody explain me why somePoint changes after

```
if somePoint == someFunc(somePoint):
```

condition?

p.s. sorry if my english is bad

Comment: You are changing the **mutable** variable inside `somePoint`. What would you expect?

Comment: Rather than modifying `somePoint` inside `someFunc`, you should just create a new point object and return that for comparison.

Comment: @JBernardo Mutability (here) is related to objects, not variables.. the variable just happens to name the (same) object that is being mutated.

Comment: @pst One thing is the name of the variable (`point`) the other is the content (the `point` instance or object) which is the variable per se.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You change the value of `point` inside function `someFunc` when you call it 
in your if-statement, so I would expect the value to be (0,0) at the
end. The reason is that you are passing a reference (or "Pass By Object Sharing") to the function and any changes to it are reflected later on. This is unlike the pass-by-value method were a local copy is automatically produced.

To avoid changing the original `point` being passed in you could create a local variable inside `someFunc`.

Something like this:

```
def someFunc(a_point): # note new parameter name

    loc_point = point(a_point.x, a_point.y)  # new local point

    if loc_point.x > 14: loc_point.x = 14
    elif loc_point.x < 0: loc_point.x = 0

    if loc_point.y > 14: loc_point.y = 14
    elif loc_point.y < 0: loc_point.y = 0

    return loc_point
```

Also, it's probably *best not* to use `point` to *both* refer to your class and your parameter.

Comment: I think the critical point here is that in Python, objects are passed *by reference*, not by value.  In C++, with a similar signature, we would expect a copy of the point to be made when the function is called.  But in Python, no such copy is made.

Comment: GRR. NO. STOP WITH "PASS BY REFERENCE". This phrase is confusing and overloaded. The semantics are better and unambiguously called "Call By Object Sharing". (End rant.)

Comment: @pst I don't think 'pass by reference' is confusing, but I added your term to my answer too if it helps make the meaning clear. Personally I have come across the former much more frequently (perhaps that dates me :)

Comment: @Levon: I think what pst means is that Python is neither exactly pass-by-reference nor pass-by-value. Pass by reference implies (to some programmers, at least) that you can do things like C-style out parameters.

Comment: @Levon The reason why it is confusing is that it has so many meanings and nuances and it *makes me think about something -- references -- that I should not need to*. "&" parameters in C++ (which *really are* "call by reference"). out/ref in C# (like reference parameters in C++). Java (which uses "pass by value [of the reference]"). ByRef vs ByVal in VB (yet the latter allows mutability as well). And JavaScript which doesn't even use the term "reference" in the specification...

Comment: @ThomasK C has *no* pass-by-reference. C is *only* pass-by-value. C gets around this with using pointers. This is why I oppose the term :)

Comment: @pst Thanks for the additional information .. I'll take some time to mull over the terminology.

Comment: @Levon But to be fair, "pass by reference" *is* the term used in the Python documentation so... I just really wish "call by object [sharing]" was more widespread ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Calling `someFunc()` uses by-reference semantics, so that the object it modifies is exactly the object you called it with. It seems you were expecting by-value semantics, where the function gets a copy of the object it was passed.